# Kivy - ScrollView in Popup within TabbedPanel not scrolling

Tags: python, interface, kivy

I made a little interface that's basically a GridLayout within which I put a Button (among other things) that calls a Popup in which there's a ScrollView with other things. The whole code works well but I tried to put the GridLayout in one of the tabs of a TabbedPanel and now the Popup won't scroll. I didn't make any changes in the code whatsoever but changing the class of my Widget to TabbedPanel.

What did I do wrong?

Relevant .py file:

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
Config.set('graphics', 'left', 100)
Config.set('graphics', 'top',  100)
Config.write()

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooser
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.effects.dampedscroll import DampedScrollEffect
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class MyWidget(TabbedPanel):

    def popupSettings(self, *args):
        list_of_choices = []
        list_chosen = []

        number_content = len(self.spinner_choices)
        contentF = ScrollView(do_scroll_x=False, size_hint_y=None, height=400)
        content = GridLayout(rows=number_content+1, cols=2, size_hint_y=None, height=self.minimum_height, spacing=30)

        for y in self.spinner_choices:
            content.add_widget(Label(text=y + " (Current value: {})".format(self.param_values[str(y)]), size_hint_y=None, height=30, size_hint_x=None, width=300))

            checkmate = CheckBox(size_hint_y=None, height=30)

            self.check_ref[y] = checkmate

            content.add_widget(checkmate)


        b = Button(text="OK", size_hint_y=None, height=30)

        content.add_widget(Label(text="Click here when you are done -> ", size_hint_y=None, height=30))
        content.add_widget(b)
        contentF.add_widget(content)

        p = Popup(title='Choose the parameters you want to change', content=contentF, auto_dismiss=False, size_hint_y=None, height=500, size_hint_x=None, width=500)
        b.bind(on_press=lambda *args:self.buttonValidation(p))
        p.open()

class TheJamApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Window.size=(768, 930)
    TheJamApp().run()
```

And the .kv file:

```
<MyWidget>:
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_width: 150
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Default'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 40
        GridLayout:
            rows: 8
            cols: 1
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5}
            height: self.minimum_height
            spacing: 20
            padding: [20,20]
            Label: [...]
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Wat'
        Button:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 40
            text:"ok"
```